Cannot mount NTFS Drive in 24.04 LTS
So i had a perfectly good system running with 22.04 LTS. was asked to upgrade to 24.04 LTS which i did 2 days ago. Now my internal storage drive which is formatted to NTFS and as all my storage on it wont mount ? WTF people say they choose Ubuntu because windows is such a pain.
I have tried through terminal some commands to try and get it to mount but no good. Can anyone offer an easy solution or do i have to go back to windows to clear up this mess.

Please share some of the commands you've tried. Also post your /etc/fstab. You mentioned Windows - is this a dual-boot system? If so, did Fast Boot get re-enabled?

Ok i have finally managed to get it to mount to Media. But now cannot access it from the desktop ?

commands I have tried.

commands I have tried.   sudo parted -l      sudo fdisk -l | grep NTFS      sudo mkdir /mnt/media       sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /mnt/media  df -hT    This is not a dual boot system I used to run Linux Mint then changed to 22.04 LTS a few years ago the drive always mounted properly in the desktop  and never had an issue until i upgraded to 24.04 LTS  I have now found in the new system i cannot move stuff to the Recycle bin off the desktop without some called Nautilus  ??  The horrors of 24.04 LTS persist   But So do I.

bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied

Can you please add the requested info to your question? The formatting on the comments is really hard to read. For the fstab, post the result of cat /etc/fstab.

Is there a reason you're using a non-Linux filesystem instead of something like ext4 or btrfs?

Windows NTFS will eventually need chkdsk which you only can do from Windows. Best to not use NTFS unless dual booting.

I have done a complete reinstall of 22.04 LTS which works perfectly with the NTFS Drive. The reason i am using that drive is it came from my windows installation and is a storage drive with lots of  stuff i need to keep.  It appears that a driver has changed in the new version which is the issue. I will upgrade to 24.04 once it catches up.  Now i have access i can slowly move everything on to a linux drive so this doesnt happen again. Thanks for all your help.

I would also add that NTFS just works ! It matters not the OS and permissions and partitions it just works.  Not like ext...Linux should embrace it.

ext4 is natively understood and optimized for Linux systems. This can lead to better integration and performance in Linux environments. ext4 offers some additional features that many Linux users like, such as online defragmentation and support for advanced journaling features. btw please post an answer to your own question to share your experiences with other Ask Ubuntu users. You can accept your own answer and get a big green checkmark to appear next to it after 24 hours.

I had the problem that - after a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.01 - an external hard drive formatted with NTFS wouldn't mount. I tried plugging it into Windows 10 (drive not recognised) and Lubuntu 24.04 (gave same report as Ubuntu about the FS). I took the plunge and used the Discs utility in Ubuntu to 'Repair Filesystem' (it is an option that appears if you click on the obvious wheel icon in Discs). It worked! Immediate access to external hard drive and precious files.

The bug is discribed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/2062972
The answer of morbius1 (post #18) does the job:
echo 'blacklist ntfs3' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/disable-ntfs3.conf


Me, I deleted U24.1, U24.04 and wait for a better release
Staying with U22; no problems reading NTFS drives
