Can't mount drive on both U24.1 or U24.04
On "FILES", I click on "OTHER LOCATIONS". The app shows all the drives available on the system. I click on my 2Tb data hard drive and a msg UNABLE TO ACCESS LOCATION. ERROR MOUNTING (drive address), WRONG FS TYPE, BAD OPTION,BAD SUPERBLOCK OF (drive addr),MISSING CODEPAGE OR HELPER PROGRAM, OR OTHER ERROR. As the title say, I did that on both U24.1 and U24.04. In U22 and before releases I never had any problems with the drive. I have dual boot with U22 + U24. If I now boot on U22 I can read/write data to the drive without any problems. If I use "DISK" I have the same problem. With "DISK ANALYZER" the drive is reported ad UNMOUNTED and impossible to MOUNT it.
Any help will be much appreciated.
The drive is a 2tb big.
BTW, how do I att a screenshot to this msg?

possibly related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527028/cannot-mount-ntfs-drive-in-24-04-lts

This question is similar to: Why do I get "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock" error?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

user68186; as NTFS. The number of partitions is irrelevant. You missing the point: the drive is OK running on U22 and before, whatever the file type, number of partitions, etc. In U24 it just doesn't mount. Looks like a bug in U24.04 and  still found by me on U24.1, although U24.1 is not a full release to public.

karel: similar yes, but none of the solutions presented solved my problem, just like on the OP. Still can't mount it. Surely this is a bug on U24; even if installing all those app or utilities or whatever that are recommend may solve the problem, I have never had to do that on previous releases. I will remove and forget U24 for some months.Bad release.

Please edit your question and add all the information you put in comments. Comments are our channel to ask you for clarification. Also note that bugs are off topic here. If you believe you find a big, file a bug report.
